# remove all text after a certain character that appears on odd lines

Tags: sed

remove all text after a certain character that appears on all odd lines

this works for every line in the file with sed

```
sed 's/;.*//'
```

how to edit this sed line so it just does all odd lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '1~2s/;.*//' file
```

The address range `1~2` will match line 1, and then every second line after that. 
The general case is `first~step` and the example in the manual is `sed -n 1~2p` which will print all odd lines.

This is a GNU extension.

The equivalent thing in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR % 2 { sub(";.*", "") } { print }' file
```

Or, as suggested by Arrow in comments:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR % 2 { $0 = $1 } { print }' file
```

which has the same effect, but instead of explicitly substituting out everything after the first `;` it uses `;` as the field separator (with `-F';'`) and then outputs only the first field (by replacing the whole input line with only the first field for odd rows).

Comment: sed: unsupported command ~

Comment: @bob Which means that you are not using GNU `sed`. What Unix are you on? On BSD systems, GNU `sed` is sometimes installed as `gsed`.

Comment: Maybe a more idiomatic awk: `awk -F\; 'NR%2{$0=$1}1' file`

Answer (score 3):

This probably might work with all `sed` version, tested on `GNU sed` though

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo;bar-baz;xyz
a;b;c
good bad. hi there
d;e
cool;hot;normal

$ sed 's/;.*//;n' ip.txt 
foo
a;b;c
good bad. hi there
d;e
cool
```

The `n` command will fetch next line but won't change anything, effectively allowing to change only odd lines

With `perl`

```
perl -pe 's/;.*// if $.%2' ip.txt
```

where `if $.%2` adds condition to perform substitution only if line number is odd